Boost serialization: Deserialization from text works fine, but I receive unregistered class error using text or binary streams
I am parallelizing our simulation code and I need to pass a complex class to other ranks. I added serialization implementation to more than 150 classes. When I save the object to a file and deserialize from it, I can reconstruct the object. However, I cannot do this using binary or text streams.
I have another class with a lot of members, which works fine for both file and stream based deserialization. My current code base has macros BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY and BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT in all the classes being serialized.
My code is really complicated to paste here with 100s of header and .cpp files. I am looking for general guidance to pinpoint the issue, and potential solutions. I also don't know how to create and isolated code to work on the issue since the class I am trying to reconstruct has a lot members and they have a lot of members too.

It is that kind of defect that is hard to help with by brief low context prose, no code, no executable to debug. Problem can be because of anything. Maybe you try to run it on Windows but do not use std::ios::binary flag when opening binary stream?

The most hidden pitfall that traps many people is that the macros do nothing unless the archive headers have been included before the point of macro invocation.
To avoid needing to know ahead of time which archives to support, consider polymorphic archives.
Here's the documentation link: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export

Note that the implemenation of this functionality requires that the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT macro appear after and the inclusion of any archive class headers for which code is to be instantiated. So, code that uses BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT will look like the following:
...
Including BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT in the "a.hpp" header itself as one would do with other serialization traits will make it difficult or impossible to follow the rule above regarding inclusion of archive headers before BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT is invoked. This can best be addressed by using BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY in the header declarations and BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT in the class definition file.
This system has certain implications for placing code in static or shared libraries. Placing BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT in library code will have no effect unless archive class headers are also included. So when building a library, one should include all headers for all the archive classes which he anticipates using. Alternatively, one can include headers for just the Polymoprhic Archives.


Thank you for your answer! However, I added the export headers properly too. Like I said, I have another complex class that can be serialized and deserialized. Should I check if I missed one? Why would deserialization from files work if that is the case?
